# stacking sparse and dense matrices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, scipy

is it possible to stack a sparse and a dense numpy array in python? I know this can be done for dense numpy arrays using vstack/hstack. I have some columns that I would like to add to a sparse matrix in order to increase the number of feature vectors

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can use `scipy.sparse.vstack` and `scipy.sparse.hstack`, in the same way as you would use `numpy.vstack` and `numpy.hstack` for dense arrays.

Example:

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
m = coo_matrix(np.array([[0,0,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,0]]))
a = np.ones(m.shape)
```

With `np.vstack`:

```
np.vstack((a,m))
#ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

With `scipy.sparse.vstack`:

```
scipy.sparse.vstack((a,m))
#<6x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
#        with 12 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```